# Labeling ticks with strings instead of its numeric value

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have a fairly long list of data points that I'm plotting using `ListPlot`. Now, instead of the x-axis saying 1000, 2000, 3000, ...; i.e., the ordinal number of the point, I want it to say "a", "b", "c", .... How could I accomplish this?

The option `Ticks` apparently can only specify at what values I want it to show the respective value, but instead of 1000, I want it to say "a" on the plot's x-axis.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1829848).

Answer (score 3):

See the documentation for [`Ticks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html)

```
SeedRandom[1234]

data = RandomReal[{0, 5200}, {10, 2}];

ListPlot[data, 
 Ticks -> {Transpose[{Range[1000, 5000, 1000], CharacterRange["a", "e"]}], 
   Automatic}]
```

[image]